# Python - extract values when conditions are true using boolean variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, if-statement, boolean

I'm extracting data from a table and I need to find the item code that meets all 4 conditions. For example, I have the lat and long for this item, the lat needs to be within this range and the long need to be within another range, and I need to extract the corresponding item codes that meet both the constraints. Using this item code, I will look for its corresponding value in another dictionary.

update:
I was working on my scripts and here's what I have now, the dictionary (dict) here is defined in the previous step, so there's nothing missing there. The code I have now can print the two records that meet the criteria, but it also print "no match".
How can I fix this so that if conditions were met, it only prints the records that meet the criteria, and if conditions were not met, it prints "no match" (only one line, not iterating for all the lines)?

Thank you!

```
for lstr in llist:
    ldata = lstr.split(',')
    item = ldata[0]
    LatA = ldata[1]
    LongA = ldata[2]
    LatB = ldata[3]
    LongB = ldata[4]

    if (LatA < 0 and LatB > 0 and LongA > 65 and LongA < 70):
        value = dict[item]
        print(something)

else:
    print("no match")
```

Comment: This example is not complete enough to really judge your problem. What I gather form your description is that you need to iterate over your data. Do you do that?

Comment: Welcome! We could use a little more information, such as a the data structure this statement is pulling from. Please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for creating a minimal, complete, and verifiable example for us to work with.

Comment: I haven't read enough to understand your issue, but I feel I should point out that your condition will automatically be `False`, always, because you need `Lat < 0` simultaneously with `Lat > 0`. I guess this is a typo?

Comment: @RobinZigmond good catch. I'm also wondering where the data is coming from such as a tuple, list, or dictionary, and whether or not they are iterating through the data structure.

Answer (score 0):

As your title says, you can use a Boolean variable to keep track of whether any matches have been found, and check it after the loop in order to print the "no match" message or not:

```
match_found = False

for lstr in llist:
    ldata = lstr.split(',')
    item = ldata[0]
    LatA = ldata[1]
    LongA = ldata[2]
    LatB = ldata[3]
    LongB = ldata[4]

    if (LatA < 0 and LatB > 0 and LongA > 65 and LongA < 70):
        value = dict[item]
        print(something)
        match_found = True

if not match_found:
    print("no match")
```

Answer (score 0):

There are actually a couple of things going on here.

First, you cannot compare a string to an integer. For instance:

```
my_str = "65"
print(my_str < 65)  # <-- RESULTS IN A `TypeError`
```

This is one of the reasons why it is super important that we know exactly what your data structure is. Simply saying it is a tuple, list, or dictionary is not really enough. I would suggest looking at [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

With that said, given than you are splitting a string, we can assume that the value returned from iterating over the list is also a string, but this might not be the most efficient way to achieve what you are trying to do.

Second, you have a typo in your code. I assume you are trying to test if `LatA` is less than zero, `LatB` is greater than zero, `LongA` is greater than 65, and **`LongB`** is less than 70; however your if-statement is testing if `LongA` is greater than 65 and less than 70.

Thirdly, your code above is not actually valid code, and the short answer to your question is yes and no depending on what exactly you are testing for, and what the desired results are. For example:

```
llist = [
    "item1, -5, 70, 5, 65",  # MEETS CRITERA
    "item2, 5, 60, -5, 75",  # DOES NOT MEET CRITERA
]

match_found = False
value = ""

for lstr in llist:
    ldata = lstr.split(',')
    item = ldata[0]
    LatA = int(ldata[1])
    LongA = int(ldata[2])
    LatB = int(ldata[3])
    LongB = int(ldata[4])

    if LatA < 0 and LatB > 0 and LongA > 65 and LongB < 70:

        #  This will get reassigned on each match. Try using
        #  value += {item}. There is also no need for a dict,
        #  you could simply use a *list* (not tuple).
        value = {item}  

        print("Match Found")
        match_found = True

if not match_found:
    print("No Match Found")
```

would provide a basic "yes, a **single** match was found in the **entire** data structure", but would continuously print "Match Found" for every single entry in your list that meets your criteria and reassign the variable `value`. You can avoid this by removing the print statement unless you absolutely need it. Perhaps a better way to approach this would be using a dictionary, for example:

```
# [LatA, LongA, LatB, LongB]

my_dict = {
    "Location #1": [-5, 70, 5, 65],
    "Location #2": [5, 60, -5, 75],
}

my_matches_list = []

for location, coords in my_dict.items():
    if coords[0] < 0 and coords[1] > 65 and coords[2] > 0 and coords[3] < 70:
        my_matches_list.append(location)

if my_matches_list:
    print("Matches Found:")
    for match in my_matches_list:
        print(" - ", match)
else:
    print("No Matches Found")

# Matches or No Matches Found Response...
# print("Matches Found" if my_matches_list else "No Matches Found")
```

Once you have populated the `my_matches_list` you can use those values to compare against your dictionary. However, this might not be what you are looking for, but it might even eliminate multiple lists or dictionaries to help reduce confusion.

Lastly, if you need to keep your code roughly the same as you posted, and you needed a more functional result than yes or no, you could do the following:

```
llist = [
    "item1, -5, 70, 5, 65",  # MEETS CRITERA
    "item2, -1, 75, 10, 15", # MEETS CRITERA
    "item3, 5, 60, -5, 75",  # DOES NOT MEET CRITERA
]

matched_values = list()

for lstr in llist:
    ldata = lstr.split(',')
    item = ldata[0]
    LatA = int(ldata[1])
    LongA = int(ldata[2])
    LatB = int(ldata[3])
    LongB = int(ldata[4])

    if LatA < 0 and LatB > 0 and LongA > 65 and LongB < 70:
        matched_values.append(item)  # += [item] works too, but not preferred.

if matched_values:
    print("Matches Found:")
    for match in matched_values:
        print(" - ", match)
else:
    print("No Matches Found")
```

This would simply test the `matched_values` list to see if it has a value, which would provide a true or false result.